# Question on the formal syntax used on MDN

Tags: css, w3c

Looking at the formal syntax for the "display" property's value on MDN, we find: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
[ <display-outside> || <display-inside> ] <display-listitem> | <display-internal> | <display-box> | <display-legacy>
```

From the docs on the syntax, **Juxtaposition** has higher precedence than **single bar** which makes me conclude that we can rewrite the syntax in the following manner:

```
[[ <display-outside> || <display-inside> ] <display-listitem> ] | <display-internal> | <display-box> | <display-legacy>
```

What I've done is just grouping `<display-outside> || <display-inside> ]` with `<display-listitem>`
Which means - If my conclusion about the grouping is right- that when using `<display-outside>` or `<display-inside>`, *or both* then they will always be followed by `<display-listitem>` because of **Juxtaposition**

But we all know that we write "display: block" or "display: flex" which are not followed by `<display-listitem>`
What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: look at the French pages explanation, even if you don't speak French  you can see  the sample code

Comment: Thanks man, I also found the correct syntax on that page: [ <display-outside> || <display-inside> ] | <display-listitem> | <display-internal> | <display-box> | <display-legacy>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MDN is clearly wrong in this case because if you check the official [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties) you can see:

```
 [ <display-outside> || <display-inside> ] | <display-listitem> | <display-internal> | <display-box> | <display-legacy>
```

There is a `|` before `<display-listitem>`

---

You can always contribute to MDN by editing the pages to correct such typos.

Check this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Howto/Create_and_edit_pages